# How find and install PHP 5.3.10 or later on CentOS 6.5?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, php

When I check `yum list php`
it only shows 5.3.3 which is older than 5.3.10.

How do I get and install the newer PHP?

(Using CentOS 6.5)

Comment: Is upgrading to a more recent version of centOS viable?

Answer (score 1):

As you write PHP 5.3.3 is the latest version of PHP for CentOS 6, but keep in mind that critical bug, security fix and so on are backported on CentOS PHP packages. You can take a look here https://serverfault.com/questions/354470/why-are-outdated-packages-installed-by-yum-on-centos-specifically-php-5-1-how

If you need a more recent PHP (5.4,.5.5,...) you can use Remi's RPM repo, to add it follow the site instructions: http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en

Answer (score 0):

First install webatic repo on your server:

```
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

Then install php by:

```
yum install php54w
```

and if you need additional package you can just check by:

```
yum list all | grep php54
```

Then search the package and install the package.